# Local storage isnt supported by my Chrome? How do I enable it?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

Well, first off, I am literally a noob in programming so forgive me if this seems a ridiculous question. Actually I was just trying my hands at App.js and then came to know about the local storage thingy. Ofcourse it is a perfect thing to have in a HTML Based Mobile App. While trying to play with local storage I did this code to check if my Chrome supported it:

```
if (typeof(storage) !== "undefined") {

                alert("Its a go!");

            } else {

                alert("Upgrade");

            }
```

But my chrome alerts the second one. Now I checked my Chrome is up to date. Firefox does the same thing as well. What should I do to enable the local storage so I can practice making some apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
typeof(storage)
```

use

```
typeof(localStorage)
```

or

```
typeof(sessionStorage)
```

**localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date

**sessionStorage** - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
typeof(localStorage)
```